# i couldn't activate windows 7 home premium, slui.exe exception

Tags: windows-7

In Windows 7 Activation there is a error reporting

```
c:\Windows\system32\slui.exe
    Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have appropriate permissions to access the item.'
```

Suggest a way without using usual activation( cmd line activation).

Comment: Maybe this one is better for [super user](http://superuser.com/). Stack overflow is primarily for programming questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.Open cmd as administrator.

2.Enter the following

```
slmgr -ipk your-key-here
slmgr -ato
```

Comment: This helped me! Thanks! :)